# How to enable the 'start' button when the last slide in Carousel Pro is showed?

Tags: dart, flutter

**Hi i want to enable my Start button when the Carousel slide is finished how can i do that ? 
My code for the moment is this**

```
RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Start', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontSize: 20.0)),
          color: Colors.blue,
          onPressed: _onPressed,
          ),
      Expanded(
        child: FittedBox(
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: SizedBox(
            key: Key('button'),
            width: queryData.size.height,
            height: queryData.size.width,
            child: Carousel(
              boxFit: BoxFit.fill,
              images: <dynamic>[
                NetworkImage('image url'),
                NetworkImage('image url'),
                NetworkImage('image url'),
              ],
              autoplay: false,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

I'm using the [carousel_pro](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/carousel_pro) package for the Carousel.

Comment: You should note that you're using the [carousel_pro](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/carousel_pro) package. It appears that it doesn't expose any listener to when the carousel finishes. You will have to extend it and provide some way to listen to when it is done looping through the images.

Comment: @KirollosMorkos Thank you for the answer.